# How to remove window.chrome in headful puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

When I launch headful puppeteer,there always is `chrome` property in `window`.

`window.chrome` like

```
{
    "app": {
        "isInstalled": false,
        "InstallState": {
            "DISABLED": "disabled",
            "INSTALLED": "installed",
            "NOT_INSTALLED": "not_installed"
        },
        "RunningState": {
            "CANNOT_RUN": "cannot_run",
            "READY_TO_RUN": "ready_to_run",
            "RUNNING": "running"
        }
    },
    "runtime": {
        "OnInstalledReason": {
            "CHROME_UPDATE": "chrome_update",
            "INSTALL": "install",
            "SHARED_MODULE_UPDATE": "shared_module_update",
            "UPDATE": "update"
        },
        "OnRestartRequiredReason": {
            "APP_UPDATE": "app_update",
            "OS_UPDATE": "os_update",
            "PERIODIC": "periodic"
        },
        "PlatformArch": {
            "ARM": "arm",
            "ARM64": "arm64",
            "MIPS": "mips",
            "MIPS64": "mips64",
            "X86_32": "x86-32",
            "X86_64": "x86-64"
        },
        "PlatformNaclArch": {
            "ARM": "arm",
            "MIPS": "mips",
            "MIPS64": "mips64",
            "X86_32": "x86-32",
            "X86_64": "x86-64"
        },
        "PlatformOs": {
            "ANDROID": "android",
            "CROS": "cros",
            "LINUX": "linux",
            "MAC": "mac",
            "OPENBSD": "openbsd",
            "WIN": "win"
        },
        "RequestUpdateCheckStatus": {
            "NO_UPDATE": "no_update",
            "THROTTLED": "throttled",
            "UPDATE_AVAILABLE": "update_available"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried `delete window.chrome` but didn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to camouflage safari browser by puppeteer.And `window.chrome` doesn't exsit in safari. @ggorlen